# File Output changes after packaging program as jar

Tags: java, jar

I have an application that writes some data to a plain text index file. It works fine in Netbeans, but when packaged as a jar the index file is created but ends up blank. Here is the relevant code:

```
System.out.println("Writing Index File");

PrintWriter indexOut = new PrintWriter(new File("index.txt"));

for(int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++)
{
    indexOut.println(index.get(i));
}

indexOut.flush();
indexOut.close();

System.out.println("Index complete.");
```

Why would the apps behavior change when I bundle it as a jar and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you specify the full path? Eg. C:\temp\index.txt

Answer (score 1):

Do you think the index collection has something?
You may want to change the first like to
System.out.println("Writing Index File " + index.size());

You can try debugging the same.

There should be no reason for the app behaviour to change, unless the input to the program changes.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are reading some data in your program from a file which is supposed to be relative to your current directory. So you should check if you have dependency on any relative path. If yes convert them to absolute path as first step.

Answer (score 0):

When you run from netbeans the default file path (where a file will land if you just write File("indexOut.txt") ) is the netbeans project folder. If you double-click the jar file, then the default path is the directory containing the jar.